# Algolia - Dynamically display remaining possible facet combinations based on already selected facet options

Tags: facet, algolia

Trying to setup some collection/category pages using Algolia facets. We have a large array of facets for various bits of data.

An example is a "collections" facet that can contain a large array of data, for example it may have the following options: "A level", "Science", "Physics", "English", "Literature".

#### Current Behaviour

The current behaviour (which we believe is default) is that if I selected Sciecne, I could then also select English which would then show me all Science AND English courses.

#### Desired Behaviour

The behaviour we are trying to obtain is the following: When any option is selected for any given facet, (Example, I select "Science") then all remaining facets should now **only** show remaining possible combinations. In our example, if I select Science, I should only be able to then select "Physics" as an option, with English/Literature no longer being available.

The use case is we would have an "A level" page where by default we could display any of dozens of sub cateogries, like Enlighs/Science/Psychologys/Art/IT/etc but as someone filters down we would like it to reduce the remaining number of possible selections to help refine a more "specific" search.

#### Research

What I've found is that we can perform custom filters that create the desired behaviour, but I'm unsure on how to generate the filters themselves to be selected from. I.e. for my above example I can add the following custom query which provides the correct results and as such there are no other unwanted facets - but generating this list initially to select what are essentially "sub-categories" I cannot figure out. We basically want to change what are currently `OR` comparisons, to `AND`

`{ "filters": "collections:a-levels AND collections:science" }`

Comment: are you doing these in a frontend